Type error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'ProgramGoals'
i try to upload a project on render but when i push it i kept have the error: Type error: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'ProgramGoals'. i d'on understand cause i have this in my prisma schema:
model ProgramGoals {
  id             String   @id @default(cuid())
  description    String   @db.Text
  start          DateTime
  end            DateTime
  position       Int
  status         STATUS    @default(PENDING)
  createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime  @updatedAt

  ProgramId      String
  Program        Program  @relation(fields: [ProgramId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  Seance         Seance[]
}

i already delete node_module && package lock json and reinstall nothing change.
i also do npx prisma generate nothing change.
i have this in my prisma schema:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}

and here my next.config.mjs:
import { hostname } from "os";

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "************",
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "************",
      },
    ],
  },
  experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["@aws-sdk"],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

can someone have already resolve this i really want to upload this project.

Okay the problems is i was using a localdatabase and not run the npm run build command
